# Assign or retain in cocos2d and objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, cocos2d-iphone

Here's my current situation:
I have a NSMutableArray named dictKeyArray which I assign a property with `@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *dictKeyArray`
I synthesize my mutable array in the implementation file. 

Later, I have a dictionary name storeDict. I assign all the keys of the dictionary to the dictKeyArray like so:
`dictKeyArray = [[storeDict allKeys] mutableCopy];`

Now I use this dictionary later in my implementation file. However, when it comes to releasing it, I release it once in my `dealloc` method. When checking with instruments, a leak shows up! Why is dictKeyArray leaking? Should I be using `assign` instead of `retain`?
I'm still not clear on what the difference is exactly...
thank you!

Comment: Do you ever change what `dictKeyArray` points to? If so, you need to release the previous value.

Comment: I keep repeating myself: get rid of these ugly memory management issues by using ARC! http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/04/enabling-arc-cocos2d-project-howto-stepbystep-tutorialguide/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send it an

```
[[[storeDict allKeys] mutableCopy] autorelease];
```

Just to make this clear: `mutableCopy` does the same as `alloc` meaning you are claiming ownership of the object in question. You have to decrease the retainCount by one.

By the way: You should use the accessor you wrote for it. You are just assigning it to your iVar at the moment. If you want to make your accessors work, you will have to use something like

```
object.dictKeyArray = ...;
```

in general. Or here (as mentioned by dreamlax)

```
self.dictKeyArray = ...;
```

because you are referring to an object of this specific class the code is in.

Only this way you are ensuring your object is properly retained by your accessor. Otherwise writing the accessor code doesn't make sense at all because it never gets called.

Please note: As Josh said in the comments, your code should be valid (at least from my point of view). What I suggested is a solution that is not as error-prone as yours because you adhere to the rules (could save you from headache in the near future).

Comment: Assigning to the ivar directly _without_ `autorelease` means that the memory management is correct. (Except for leaking whatever was already in `dictKeyArray`.)

Comment: Yeah. You are completely right. There shouldn't be a leak (at least at this point). I advised him to do so because it's the best way to do it at all. **BUT** As Josh said: What I said is doing some kind of, well, nothing at all. At first you release it, in order to retain it again. Difference +-0. My post was to ensure he won't run into problems in the future by doing nonsense and not adhering to the valid and useful rules, that is: Always use accessors. Only this ensures you are good to go in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `self.dictKeyArray = ...`. Without the `self.` you are accessing the instance variable directly, bypassing any memory management benefits of properties, but, remember that you own the result of `mutableCopy`, and assigning to a property that also takes ownership will result in double-ownership, so use:

```
self.dictKeyArray = [[[storeDict allKeys] mutableCopy] autorelease];
```

Comment: Hm...Interesting. So what exactly does the added self. do? What are the memory management benefits of properties that are missed without the self.? Thanks!

Comment: self ensures your accessor really gets called. What you do is assigning your iVar another object reference. This is not what you want. self is a reference to the object the messages are called on (an instance of your class, this code belongs to).

Comment: The `self.` ensures you are using the property accessor methods. `self.dictKeyArray = ...` is exactly equivalent to `[self setDictKeyArray:...]` which is the method that you declared and synthesised. If you forget `self.` then you are not using any accessor method.